# Getting a planche with only psuedo planche push ups

Tags: gymnastics

i don't like weight training, the idea of having to travel to the gym, having to deal with people and waiting for machines or barbells sucks.

plus I like training shirtless, which I can't in a gym.

i also hate normal push ups, they don't cause me any pain but I just don't like the sensation they leave.

the idea of a planche looks cool, I wanna be able to do planche push ups.

and I was wondering if it's possible to learn it just by doing psuedo planche push ups with hands at hip height like in this photo.

[image]

i can do 12 in a row cest to floor. and I prefer them to normal push ups because I feel all the pressure in my arms and not my chest.... I don't like chest training generally, an arm or leg pump feels awesome but a chest pump is a different feeling, not enjoying it all. sometimes  I get a chest pump from pull ups but it's different from the one you get from doing pressing movements.

so anyone here expert in gymanstics who knows if it's possible to learn a planche without static training and by only doing psuedo planche push ups?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: You need to do more than just psuedo planche pushups.**

> if it's possible to learn a planche by only doing psuedo planche push ups?

I wouldn't say so. Doing psuedo planche pushups helps and it a good progression tool, but you need to work your entire body to be able to hold a planche. Chest, shoulders, scapula, core. To a certain extent you even need to train your glutes and hamstrings, you need to improve all of this in order to keep your body in that position.

I would advice to start out with easier exercises that complement each other in order to grow into the planche, psuedo planche pushups is one of them. Other exercises can be normal pushups, scapula pushpus, dips, planks, frog stand, advanced frog stand, tuck planche, you name it.

> if it's possible to learn a planche without static training

What exactly do you mean by static training? If you mean weight training, no you don't need to do any weight training (though it could help a lot). You can train every part of the body without going to a gym.

Answer (score 0):

You sound really picky.

> i don't like weight training

I find that a lot of people have a knee-jerk hatred of the gym and lifting weights. In a lot of cases it seems to be some weird social thing. I guess many folks were turned off by the steroids-driven bodybuilding craze of the 1980s.

This is not a good reason to avoid lifting weights if you actually want to get strong.

> he idea of having to travel to the gym, having to deal with people and waiting for machines or barbells sucks.

Have you even *tried* it? It's not so bad. Give it a shot instead of making up reasons not to.

> I like training shirtless, which I can't in a gym.

You know, there are barbells and dumbbells and kettlebells you could buy to lift at home, as nude as you care to be.

> i also hate normal push ups...I just don't like the sensation

> I don't like chest training generally

Your reasons to avoid training are starting to sound pathological. If you don't want to train chest, don't train chest. But horizontal pressing motions are going to require working your chest. Avoiding chest training is another thing I see from people who want to get strong but have an aversion to somehow being "like" or training like Arnold Schwarzennegger. This is not a productive attitude to have.

I encourage you to prove me wrong, to train hard as hell but not do any chest work, and prove me wrong. That would be badass. But so would overcoming your dislike of weights and getting strong as hell with whole-body resistance training.